# Не могу понять куда сохраняются данные select multiply?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите как получить данные в массиве из select multiply?

```
<form action="#" id="carsSelection" v-if="vehicleItem">
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <label class="col-form-label filter-label">Выберите автомобиль</label>
<select class="form-select" aria-label="multiple select example" size='10' form="carsSelection" multiple="multiple">
  <option selected>Автомобили не выбраны</option>
  <option :value="auto.name" v-for="auto of vehicleItem" :key="auto.id">
    {{ auto.name }}</option>
</select>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success">Сохранить выбор</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через `v-model`, как и в любых полях формы:

```
<template>
    <select v-model="selectedValues" multiple>
      <option selected>Автомобили не выбраны</option>
      <option :value="auto.name" v-for="auto in vehicleItem" :key="auto.id"> {{ auto.name 
    }}</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            selectedValues: []
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

В `selectedValues` (из примера, переменнюу можете назвать как угодно) будете получать массив с выбранными значениями из `values`

Comment: Все насколько просто оказалось) Спасибо, а я немного намудрил)

Comment: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'**

Comment: @Опан И что Вы этим хотите сказать? Вы вообще писали что-то на Vue?

Comment: Я подключил Vue, ошибка осталась.

Comment: @Опан В ответе приведен конструктор компонента (классический вариант, без setup). Он не запускается просто так, поскольку компилируется через Webpack. Автор вопроса понял, что нужно делать. Если у Вас есть вопрос, как использовать Vue – прочтите документацию или задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Но "к сожалению" тему читает ещё множество, не только автор. Обязательно ли для решения элементарного вопроса использовать Vue? Имеет ли наглядность Ваш код для тех, кто не знает Vue, но хочет прочитать результат выбора из селекта? А применять теги <template> ... </template> и чтобы код был реактивным для понимания работы такого примера обязательно?

Comment: @Опан Ещё раз прочитайте вопрос автора и теги. Да, для вопроса по Vue необходимо использовать Vue и применять его разметку (ваш КЭП).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134904/discussion-between--and-vladimir-gonchar).

Comment: Наконец увидел зацепку - v-if, v-for в коде автора, и метку Vue. До чего не внимателен.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем такой JS-код:

```js
var myselect = document.querySelector('select');
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
    var values = [];
     // перебираем массив опций
    for(var i = 0; i < myselect.options.length; i ++) if(myselect.options[i].selected) values.push(myselect.options[i].value); // если опция выбрана - добавим её в массив
    console.log(values);
}
```

Comment: Плохой вариант. Зачем костылить что-то на ванильном JS, если используется фреймворк, в основе которого есть работа с такими задачами? При чём приведенный код не реактивен.